# React Native Can't require module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Using something like

`require('./foo');`

Works fine. However, if I store the path in a variable and use

```
let path = 'foo';
require('./' + path);
```

React native tells me that it is an unknown module. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

require does not support dynamic loading of modules. Javascript files are statically analysed. Hence it throws up that error. See Similar issue at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481